# OnvifClientPTZ onvif c++ unable to get configuration options

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap, onvif

```
tt__Profile *t = profiles.Profiles.at(0);

OnvifClientPTZ PTZ(onvifDevice);

_tptz__GetConfigurationOptions tptz__GetConfigurationOptions;
_tptz__GetConfigurationOptionsResponse  tptz__GetConfigurationOptionsResponse;
tt__PTZConfigurationOptions *options; 

int response = PTZ.GetConfigurationOptions(tptz__GetConfigurationOptionsResponse, t->token);
```

Problem is that PTZ#GetConfigurationOptions returns value of 1 (#response).
Object #onvifDevice seems to be fine (onvifDevice.hasPTZ returns true).
I've tried debugging and onvifDevice.GetPTZUrl(strUrl) returns true and sets strUrl to 192.168.1.88:2000/device/services which is soap_endpoint of PtzProxy object (ptzProxy.soap_endpoint =  strUrl.c_str();) and it seems to be fine. Also soap_action is "www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl/GetConfigurationOptions" which also seems to be fine.
I'm using https://github.com/xsmart/onvifcpplib.

In PTZ proxy returns here:

```
tptz__GetConfigurationOptionsResponse->soap_get(soap, "tptz:GetConfigurationOptionsResponse", "");
if (soap->error)
    return soap_recv_fault(soap, 0);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Problem was in this line:

```
int response = PTZ.GetConfigurationOptions(tptz__GetConfigurationOptionsResponse, t->token);
```

OnvifPTZClient#GetConfigurationOptions requests PTZConfiguration token, not profile token. So correct line would be:

```
response = PTZ.GetConfigurationOptions(tptz__GetConfigurationOptionsResponse, tr->PTZConfiguration->token);
```